# What's the source of this saying on quantity vs. quality in friendship?

Tags: quote

> “To get to know your friends, you have to go through success and
> disgrace. In success, we check the quantity and, in disgrace, the
> quality.”

That's been translated from Portuguese, where it seems much more common.

> “Para conhecermos os amigos é necessário passar pelo sucesso e pela
> desgraça. No sucesso, verificamos a quantidade e, na desgraça, a
> qualidade.”

It's often attributed to Confucius. But I couldn't find it anywhere, and the lack of genuine English versions is intriguing by itself. Maybe I'm using the wrong English words. But a search for “friend” at [ctext’s Analects](https://ctext.org/analects?searchu=friend) leads to no useful result. The same in [Mencius](https://ctext.org/mengzi?searchu=friend), [Da Xue](https://ctext.org/liji/da-xue?searchu=friend) (The Great Learning) or [Zhong Yong](https://ctext.org/liji/zhong-yong?searchu=friend) (The Doctrine of the Mean).

Does anyone know where this saying come from?

EDIT

A different version:

> Fortune makes friends. Disgrace proves if they really exist.

> A fortuna faz amigos. A desgraça prova se eles existem de fato.